# 準備は丸一日した is there a particle missing?

Tags: grammar, translation

I was wondering for this line:

> 緊張してるの？準備は丸一日しただろう。

Let's say A says this line to B. Does it sound alright id I say:

"You prepared the whole day, didn't you?." (so, why are you nervous?).
If I rearrange the sentence as 丸一日準備をしただろう is it the same meaning?

Is 丸一日した an adverb here? Kinda feel that maybe the に particle was left out, is it the case? (the character A who speaks has a colloquial way of talking, with many informal, shortened phrases, so I'm thinking that leaving out some words is appropriate for him).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

丸一日した is not an adverb (it clearly includes した which is a verb), but 丸一日 is adverbial. Nothing is omitted after 丸一日 because it works as an adverb on its own. Remember that `number + counter` works as an adverb that describes an amount in Japanese:

- リンゴを2個買います。
- 鉛筆を1本ください。

The same goes for a time length:

- 日本に3日滞在しました。
- 15年間東京に住んでいます。
- 10分待ってください。

丸一日 is in the same vein. 丸一日準備(は/を/φ)しただろう means the same thing. に is used to describe *when* something happens (e.g., 1998年に = *in* 1998; 日曜日に = *on* Sunday), but it never marks a time length.

Comment: thank you for the explanation!